# Dropzone.js - acceptedFiles from select box not working

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I want to be able to change the `acceptedFiles` option of a Dropzone element when the user changes the option they've selected from a `<select>` element. A bit like this code `Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { acceptedFiles: selected_value};`

So far I've tried two approaches:

HTML select box:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cond_file_type" name="cond_file_type">
    <option>-- File Type --</option>
    <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
    <option value="docx">DOCX</option>
    <option value="xlsx">XLSX</option>
    <option value="png">PNG</option>
    <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
    <option value="gif">GIF</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
// Attempt 1
document.getElementById("cond_file_type").onchange = function(){
    var file_type = '.' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        acceptedFiles: file_type,
    };
};


// Attempt 2
var file_type = '';
document.getElementById("cond_file_type").onchange = function () {
    file_type = '.' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    acceptedFiles: file_type,
};
```

I tried 1 and 2 but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both options involve changing a variable after it has been read for the last time. Option 2 is most instructive in this regard; as the script is executed the following happens:

```
// file_type is set to ''
var file_type = '';
document.getElementById("cond_file_type").onchange = function () {
    // This line is not run until later when the user changes the select box.
    file_type = '.' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
// So file_type is still set to ''
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    // accepted files is set to '', regardless of what the user later selects.
    acceptedFiles: file_type,
};
```

However even in option 1, the `Dropzone.options` object is only read when creating the dropzone for the first time, so once the page has loaded there's still no point in editing it.

I can't immediately see from Dropzone's documentation a way of editing the configuration after the dropzone has been created, so I would suggest that you recreate a new dropzone with the new option every time, broadly like (**code not tested**):

```
document.getElementById("cond_file_type").onchange = function () {
    // This line is not run until later when the user changes the select box.
    var file_type = '.' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzonesId", {
        acceptedFiles: file_type,
        url: "/file/post"
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you!
I want dropzone just accept file type from select box.
Do you have any solution for this?